# Retrieving maximum column size

Tags: mysql

Example: Create Table SchoolStuff(Name Varchar(20));

Is query I can do to specify "Name" in School Stuff and end up returning the value of 20? (The maximum size the Column will accept)

Comment: You need to specify which DBMS you are using (eg. SQL Server, MySQL, etc)

Comment: @Nicarus Sorry about that! I entered it in the main post.

Comment: Did my answer get you what you needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query the columns table in the info schema.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/columns-table.html

```
SELECT
    CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
    TABLE_NAME = 'mytable' AND
    COLUMN_NAME = 'mycolumn';
```